# IE7 compatibility: 2 separate websites or one cross browser one

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

Unfortunately I have to support IE7 for a web application I'm currently developing. This website makes heavy use of frameworks such as Bootstrap and AngularJS. I will get a lot of compatibility issues with IE7 and basically I have 2 options of how to solve this:

1. Make one website which supports all browsers.
2. Make a fork of the website for IE7 only.

For both solutions I know the steps I have to take to make the website compatible with IE7. However, I want to spend as little time as possible making (and keeping) the website compatible for IE7, and thus I'm trying to find out which approach will work best.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these methods?

Comment: I accept that the whole point of asking the question is that you *have* to support IE7, and I'm sure you've already done what you can to try to rule it out, but I think it's important to double-check this, because IE7 usage has dropped off a cliff in the past months; there really is hardly anyone using it any more. Are you *sure* you need to support it? Are you *sure* that the extra work will be worth it given how few people will ever see it? If you're in control of the billing for this project, are you charging extra for IE7 support?

Comment: To give you a little more background: I'm currently in charge of rebuilding an entire website (the current one is a mess). I really really want to drop IE7 support, but we have a few paying customers who still use IE7. Currently it will cost more to drop those customers than it does to make us build an IE7 compatible version, thus my boss wants us to support IE7. However, I do suspect that in the near future these customers will drop IE7, but I'm not really sure when.